# Unable to publish node.js app from VS2015 using VS publish

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I’ve got a node.js project which I’m using to publish to Azure. This worked fine the first couple of times I’ve published, but now when I try and publish it just fails with no error message. The output in the Azure Service Activity window in VS2015 is simply:

```
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
```

And the output from the ouput/build window is:

```
------ Publish started: Project: node, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don’t really know where to start diagnosing this as there is no error message per se.
Things I’ve tried thus far:

- Full Clean and/or rebuild
- Deleted all folders from the BIN directory
- Deleted all folders from the obj directory
- Tried both debug and release configurations
- Deleting the publish profile from VS and re-adding it from scratch

None of the above has made any difference
Has anyone seen this issue before or could suggest where to start diagnosing the cause?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. A previously working (2015RC) web project published to Azure will no longer publish. Right clicking the project and clicking project does nothing. Going into Azure App Service Activity and clicking "Edit Publish Profiles" gives the error "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"

Comment: If you right-click and publish on each node in your solution in turn, you can narrow down the issue - I eventually found the files that was giving this error:  Error deserializing string. String larger than expected.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FAILED_TO_DESERIALIZE.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have GhostDoc installed?

Uninstalling it fixed it for me after seeing [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/39) issue.

Comment: No, I dont have that installed I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was due to file paths getting long more than the allowed number of characters. use this module to make your file paths shorter, and it will fix this issue
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-packages